# Collect_LIST specification in KSQL

Tags: ksqldb

the KSQL Spec for Collect_LIST says that:

> his version limits the size of the result Array to a maximum of 1000
>   entries and any values beyond this limit are silently ignored.

The Silent is particularly annoying. I would need a version that is unlimited. I need to use it with KTable.

I am thinking of implementing a user defined function for that, however, before i embark into that journey, i would like to understand why is it that there is this arbitrary limit ? can it be configured somehow ?

EDIT1:

Can work it with a Table:

```
select addressid, collect_list(name) from users group by addressid;
    The aggregation function(s) (collect_list) cannot be applied to a table.
    Statement: select addressid, collect_list(name) from users group by addressid;
    Caused by: The aggregation function(s) (collect_list) cannot be applied to a
        table.
```

Is the specification wrong ?

Comment: 1000 is a initial default limit. Well, KSQL is still maturing and adding new features/improvement in each release so in future it can be configurable. Also to be noticed, if the limit is unlimited, it can exceed the message.size and you will have to change the default values of kafka configs. Well, you can report an issue on KSQL github to address this.

Comment: Just checked, and the function is not available on KTable, is there any specific reason why ? Before we tryto implement it, ourself ?

Comment: It is available for Streams & Table, both according to 5.2.1.

Comment: Can you confirm that it works on your side ? This is what i get with 5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The 1000 limit is there as guard rails. As the list gets larger the cost of deserializing, updating and serializing the row to the underlying rocksdb store would become prohibitively expensive.

Totally agree this should be configurable. You can either cut your own UDF, or submit a PR to ksql to make it configurable!

The second question about the error: "cannot be applied to a table.".  This is because the source used in a GROUP BY is a TABLE, not a STREAM.

It's not possible to create variants of every aggregate function that can work on a STREAM source that work on TABLES.  Unlike streams, tables can have rows removed from them. The implication of this is that some aggregate functions would need to keep the full history of every value they've ever seen to be able to support one of those values being removed.  This is obviously not possible. Hence some aggregate functions can't work on table sources.

If `COLLECT_LIST` was unlimited, then there would be no reason why it couldn't work on tables, as it has all the values, but as it is limited it can't know if a value being deleted is one its tracked or one it ignored.